# Unwanted space around custom fonts

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a custom font for my website with the help of @font-face kit. But theres some unwanted space inside the tag. I've used h1 tag. Changing the tag doesn't help. [image: Spacing in Chrome and IE]

Take a look at the picture. In Chrome and others, theres lot of space on top. But in IE the space is below. Any solution for this?

Code -

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'kozukalight';
src:url('fonts/kozgopr6nlight.eot');
src:url('fonts/kozgopr6nlight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/kozgopr6nlight.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('fonts/kozgopr6nlight.ttf') format('truetype'),     
    url('fonts/kozgopr6nlight.svg#kozukalight') format('svg');
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;  
}

h1 {
font: 60px 'kozukalight', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
color: #383838;
}     

<body>
<h1>News and Events</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post code or a jsfiddle.

Comment: what did you use to get it in Chrome like that? Show us some css please

Comment: Try adjusting the `line-height`

Comment: You could also try `vertical-align: baseline;` Just in case IE's doing something weird

Comment: pzin and DiederikEEn - I've posted the code.

Comment: Adan - line-height isn't working properly in all browsers.

Comment: gaynorvader- didn't work

Comment: You can try what @gaynorvader said or line-height

Comment: @SagarRaj to notify users put `@` in the beginning otherwise they won't see your replies here.

Answer (score 0):

This got nothing to do with the custom font. `<h1>` has default margin so you have to get rid of it:

```css
h1 {
    font: 60px 'kozukalight', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    color: #383838; padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yCUs/) with default behavior (lots of "space" like you describe) and [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yCUs/1/) with the margin set to 0.

Comment: Shadow Wizard - The space is inside the h1 tag not outside :) I've used Eric Myer's reset which resets every tag in the beginning.